# How to convert multiple <br/> tag to a single <br/> tag in php

Tags: php, html, regex

Wanted to convert

```
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
```

into

```
<br/>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a PHP program that will input an HTML file and reduce the BR tags?  It's not entirely clear from your question.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression:

```
preg_replace("/(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/", "<br/>", $input);
```

This if you pass in your source HTML, this will return a string with a single <br/> replacing every run of them.

Comment: Does it ignore whitespace between the <br/>?

Comment: this allows for any whitespace chars (space, tab, newline) between <br/>

Comment: @Sam: the \s means 'any whitespace character'.

Comment: @levik: you should change it to /(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/ for a more robust/general matching of HTML/SGML/XHTML br's.

Comment: @levik: shouldn't the replace string be "<br />"?  Your code currently outputs <br\/> to the HTML.

Comment: @levik isn't it legal to have <br / >?  Wouldn't you want that to be replaced?  I'd add \s after your optional closing slash, but before your closing '>"

Answer (score 17):

Mine is almost exactly the same as [levik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php#133600)'s (+1), just accounting for some different br formatting:

```
preg_replace('/(<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/', '<br/>', $sInput);
```

Comment: Slightly better than levik's, and should even be faster.

Answer (score 6):

Enhanced readability, shorter, produces correct output regardless of attributes:

```
preg_replace('{(<br[^>]*>\s*)+}', '<br/>', $input);
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks all..
Used Jakemcgraw's (+1) version

Just added the case insensative option..

```
{(<br[^>]*>\s*)+}i
```

Great tool to test those Regular expressions is:

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Answer (score 2):

Use a regular expression to match `<br/>` one or more times, then use preg_replace (or similar) to replace with `<br/>` such as levik's reply.

Answer (score 2):

without preg_replace, but works only in PHP 5.0.0+

```
$a = '<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />';
while(($a = str_ireplace('<br /><br />', '<br />', $a, $count)) && $count > 0)
{}
// $a becomes '<br />'
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a Regular Expression.  I haven't tested the following, but I believe it's right.

```
$text = preg_replace( "/(<br\s?\/?>)+/i","<br />", $text );
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast, non regular-expression approach:

```
while(strstr($input, "<br/><br/>"))
{
    $input = str_replace("<br/><br/>", "<br/>", $input);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

User may enter many variants

```
<br>
<br/>
< br />
<br >
<BR>
<BR>< br>
```

...and more.

So I think it will be better next

```
$str = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*?br[^>]*?>\s*){2,}/i', '<br>', $str);
```