# php: trim br tags from the beginning of a string?

Tags: php, regex

I know that:

```
preg_replace('<br\s*\/?>', '', $string);
```

will remove all br tags from $string...

How can we remove all `<br><br/><br />` tags only if they are in the very beginning of $string? ($string in my case is html code with various tags...)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add an appropriate anchor (`^`):

```
preg_replace('/^(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/', '', $string);
```

This will match multiple `<br>`s *at the beginning* of the string.

`(?:…)` is a *non-capturing* group since we only use the parentheses here to group the expression, not capture it. The modifier isn’t strictly necessary – `(…)` would work just as well, but the regular expression engine would have to do more work because it then needs to remember the position and length of each captured hit.

Comment: you'll be needing delimiters around your regex and since nothing needs to be captured, use a non-capturing group `(?:...)`

Comment: @salathe: Yup … I’ve added them. I just copied the question’s code at first, that’s why I forgot them. – And the non-capturing group is a good idea, too.

Comment: thanks for the anchor tip, that's what I was missing... your regex doesn't remove all occurrences but combined with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php the correct regex should be /^(<br\s*\/?>\s*)+/
change it and I'll mark the answer as accepted

Comment: @Thanos: Well, from your question it sounded as though there were no whitespaces between the `<br>`s …

Comment: Thank you for the non capturing group knowledge drop!

Comment: @KonradRudolph How can I trim both sides? I need to add $, but where?

Comment: @user2356198 That would be a different regex altogether, you match either at the beginning *or* at the end. In other words, you need to concatenate the two regex via an alternation.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the [delimiters for PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) in your regular expression. Try this:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*/i', '', $string);
```

This will also remove leading whitespace characters before, between and after the line break tags.

Some explanation:

- `^\s*` will match any whitespace characters at the start of your string
- `(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*` will match zero or more occurrences of `BR` tags (both HTML and XHTML) followed by optional whitespace characters

Answer (score 2):

```
$string = preg_replace( '@^(<br\\b[^>]*/?>)+@i', '', $string );
```

Should match:

```
<br>
<br/>
<br style="clear: both;" />
etc
```

Comment: Careful now - the asker wanted it to work on a particular limited set of HTML, which allowed to avoid [Cthulu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Madness lies in the path of your "etc". :) Though I agree, <br style="clear:both;" /> is common enough to consider, so upvoted.

Comment: This seems to work for what I was looking for. Does this work on any legitimate `<br>` tag?