# How to Regex-replace multiple <br /> tags with one <br /> tag?

Tags: php, regex

I want `<br /><br />` to turn into `<br />`

What's the pattern for this with regex?

Note: The `<br />` tags can occur more than 2 times in a row.

Comment: CHeck out this answer
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php)

Comment: Also check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You *could* use `s/(<br \/>)+/<br \/>/`, but if you are trying to use regex on HTML you are likely doing something wrong.

**Edit:** A slightly more robust pattern you could use if you have mixed breaks:

`/(<br\ ?\/?>)+/`

This will catch `<br/>` and `<br>` as well, which might be useful in certain cases.

Comment: In javascript it's adviced to add 'gi' flags for a global search and case insensitive replace: `msg.replace(/(<br ?\/?>)+/gi, '');`

Answer (score 40):

```
$html = preg_replace('#(<br */?>\s*)+#i', '<br />', $html);
```

This will catch any combination of `<br>`, `<br/>`, or `<br />` with any amount or type of whitespace between them and replace them with a single `<br />`.

Comment: +1 for including possible whitespace between the tags. Better still would be: `'#<br\s*/?>(?:\s*<br\s*/?>)+#i'` (This one does the replace only if there is more than one.)

Comment: the previous comment is actually the only accurate solution to this question

Answer (score 0):

`(<br />)+`

Will match them so you could use `preg_replace` to replace them (remember to correctly escape characters).

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @FtDRbwLXw6 is great although it does not account for `&nbsp;` spaces. We can extend this regex to include that as well:

```
$html = preg_replace('#(<br *\/?>\s*(&nbsp;)*)+#', '<br>', $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. It works with all the combinations below.

```
$html = '<br><br>
Some text
<br>
<br>
Some another<br/><br>';

$html = preg_replace("/(<br.*?>\s*)+(\n)*+(<br.*?>)/","<br>",$html);
```

`$html` will be changed to

```
<br>
Some text
<br>
Some another<br>
```