# PHP - Remove duplicate HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a PHP string with an unknown number of `br` tags. I need to keep only one.

**Start string**

```
$str = 'A line of string data<br><br><br><br>with duplicate br tags in here.';
$str2 = 'Another line with 5 br tags this time.<br><br><br><br><br>New line.';
$str3 = 'When it<br /><br><br />breaks';
```

**Result**

```
$str = 'A line of string data<br>with duplicate br tags in here.';
$str2 = 'Another line with 5 br tags this time.<br>New line.';
$str3 = 'When it<br>breaks';
```

**My thoughts**

- First I used `str_replace('<br>', '', $str)`. It don't go that well because the number of duplicate tags in a row are unknown.
- Some clever regex might solve it? or another solution?
- Would be nice if it would work with or without ending slash. `<br><br />`

Comment: `preg_replace('#(<br\s?/?>)+#', '<br>', $str);` happy coding :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738439/how-to-regex-replace-multiple-br-tags-with-one-br-tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7738597/2106973

Answer (score 3):

Try this..

```
$str = 'A line of string data<br><br><br><br>with duplicate br tags in here.';
echo preg_replace('#(<br\s?/?>)+#', '<br>', $str);
```

**Output**

```
A line of string data<br>with duplicate br tags in here.
```

Comment: I would use `#(<br\s*/?>)+#` instead of `#(<br\s?/?>)+#`.

Answer (score 1):

This will find all instances of the br tag followed by multiple br tags.

`(<([bB][Rr]\b)[^>]{0,}>(?:<\2[^>]{0,}>){1,})`

[image]

[image]