# Detect <br /> in string and wrap text with paragraph tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsing

Is it possible to parse a string in JavaScript such that if blocks of text are separated by 2 `<br />` tags instead of paragraph breaks, each text block gets wrapped in opening and closing `<p>` tags? Here's a sample text:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. 
<br />
<br />
Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
```

Desired result would be:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc. </p>
<p>Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
```

Thank you.

**Update**: If text already has `<p>` tags, it shouldn't get wrapped in extra tags.

Comment: Look at this question for regex to find multiple br tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738439/how-to-regex-replace-multiple-br-tags-with-one-br-tag I would use that regex with a replace function

Comment: Sure! Show us what you've t ried so far.

Comment: The HTML content that you wrote above, it may or may not be in a p tag? So what you're saying is that the Lorem ipsum you included with the br tags could be inside a div or span tag or other?

Comment: No, it can have `<p>` tags but the text won't be in `<div>` or other tags.

Comment: So the text you wrote above will ALWAYS be inside a p tag?

Comment: Yes, it will always need to get wrapped in `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on @Radonirina's answer.

```
var string = "your string........";
var result = "<p>";
result += string.replace(/<[br][^>]\s*\/?>/ig, '</p><p>');
result += "</p>";
```

#### OR  (non-regex)

```
var string = "string ...  ";
var stringArr = string.split('<br />');
var para = '<p>';
para += stringArr.join('</p><p>');
para += '</p>';
```

### UPDATE :

Use this function to remove blank element from array in method 2.

```
Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

test = new Array("","One","Two","", "Three","","Four").clean("");

test2 = [1,2,,3,,3,,,,,,4,,4,,5,,6,,,,];
test2.clean(undefined);
```

### Final Answer

```
var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.  <br /><br />Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. ";
var stringArr = string.split('<br />');

Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] == deleteValue) {         
      this.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    }
  }
  return this;
};

stringArr.clean('');

var para = '<p>';
para += stringArr.join('</p><p>');
para += '</p>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex: `/<[br][^>]\s*\/?>/g`

https://regex101.com/r/zD8uI0/1

Answer (score 1):

use regex for some cases such as <br> < br > <br/> <br />.

```
var text = .....
text = '<p>' + text + '</p>';
text = text.replace('<br />', '</p><p>');//this will replace br tag only once. Use regex with 'g' modificator.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this is exactly what you want. It accounts for possible whitespace characters between the `<br/>` tags and also works if more than 2 `<br />` tags are present and works for multiple br tag formats including `<br>`, `<br/>`, `<br >` and `<br />`

**HTML**

```
$(function () {
    $("body").html(
        $("body").html().replace(/((<br\ ?\/?>)(\s*)?){2}/igm, "</p><p>")
    );
});
```

**JS**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.
    <br />
    <br />
Curabitur tortor. Pellentesque nibh. Aenean quam. In scelerisque sem at dolor. Maecenas mattis. Sed convallis tristique sem. Proin ut ligula vel nunc egestas porttitor. Morbi lectus risus, iaculis vel, suscipit quis, luctus non, massa. Fusce ac turpis quis ligula lacinia aliquet. Mauris ipsum. Nulla metus metus, ullamcorper vel, tincidunt sed, euismod in, nibh. Quisque volutpat condimentum velit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.</p>
```

Here, I've included a jsfiddle for you in case the above snippet gives you issues: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/wf1uL9y7/

Comment: your embedded JSfiddle just crashed my browser btw... (Chrome version 43.0.2357)

Comment: I broke the browser, great haha.

Comment: Just use the fiddle then, I will remove the snippet