# Replace multiple br tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have some text:

`Production Manager.<br>Responsibilities: Manage operations with emphasis on optimizing productivity, quality and safety.<br>This position is responsible for<br>`

`</br><Br>assigned manufacturing area(s) and oversees all aspects of that area, including labor, production, yield, sanitation, etc.<br>within established budgeted cost parameters.<br>`

I am trying to write regular expression that replaces three `br` tags continuous or more and replaces them with two `br`: `<br/><br/>`

the three or more `br`-s can spliited by spaces of new line only.

the `br` tag can be:

`<br>`
`<br/>`
`<br />`

or with uppercase.

for examples:

`<br><br><br>` will be replaced to `<br/><br/>`

`<BR><Br><br />` will be replaced to `<br/><br/>`

`<br /><BR/><br />` will be replaced to `<br/><br/>`

`<br><br><BR><br>` will be replaced to `<br/><br/>`

etc.

I found this link:

[How to Regex-replace multiple <br /> tags with one <br /> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738439/how-to-regex-replace-multiple-br-tags-with-one-br-tag)

and tried this:

`/((<BR|<br)?\W?\/?(\s)>)/g`

with no success.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So like find `(?:<(?:br|BR)\s*/?>){3}`, replace `<br/><br/>`. Its easier to write an expression if you say it out loud.

Comment: `br` tags may have attributes. There may be newlines inbetween, too. Maybe using an HTML parser is still a better option here. :)

Comment: The forward slashes at the beginning and end are probably for JavaScript.  You don't want those in .Net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned before, an HTML parser might be the way to go if your `br` tags have attributes.

Try this regular expression:
`(</?([bB][rR])\s*/?>\n*\s*){3,}`

It will handle spaces and newlines in between tags.  Attributes are another story, however.  You could potentially modify the regex to allow ANY characters inside the `br` tag, but there could be some issues with that.