# Limit preserved linebreaks for textarea

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, textarea

Ok, so I have linebreaks preserved when being uploaded to my database and they are seen when displayed on a webpage, but I have an issue. My website is a forum and I don't want a user to have a topic with an excessive amount of linebreaks between text... for example:

```
line 1
<1 blank line>
<2 blank lines>
<3 blank lines>
<4 blank lines>
line 2
<1 blank line>
<2 blank lines>
line 3
```

That is going to make my page much longer than it needs to be and will just cause an unpleasant page. Is there anyway I can make it where only 1 new line can be added between text lines, for example

```
line 1
<1 blank line>
line 2
<1 blank line>
line 3
```

Thank you for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this using multiple approaches:

Using Regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^[ \t]*[\r\n]+/m', '', $content);
echo (nl2br($str));
```

Custom function:

```
echo removeBlankLines($content);
function removeBlankLines($content = null)
{
   $lines = explode("\n", $content);
   $temp  = array();
   foreach ($lines as $line) {
       $last = end($temp);
       if($line == '' && $last == $line) continue;

       $temp[]   = $line;
       $result[] = $line ? $line : "\n";
   }

   return ($result) ? (nl2br(join('', $result))) : false;
}
```

Input:

```
$content = 'line 1



line 2



line 3';
```

Output:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Comment: Thank you! This was great and fixed the problem!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for (I assume the posts on your forum are formatted in HTML, but you can apply the same logic for `\n` if you have the text before HTML formatting - see [MBaas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745053/limit-preserved-linebreaks-for-textarea/32745145#32745145)):

[How to Regex-replace multiple <br /> tags with one <br /> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738439/how-to-regex-replace-multiple-br-tags-with-one-br-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have access to the "raw data" before it goes into the DB, you could do a string-search for consecutive newlines and replace with one linefeed - probably a regex such as `\n{2,}` would do the job.

In PHP, it would something like `$result = preg_replace('/\n{2,}/', '\n', $subject);`

Comment: I'm getting the data right from the contact form. I tried this and tried it using "<br>" and "<br/>" instead of "/n", but it still didn't change anything

Comment: So can you do a `var_dump` of your variable to check how it handles the linebreaks?

Comment: Goes from "sdfgsdfg", 2 linebreaks(just pressing enter), and "sdfgsdfsdfg" in the textarea to a var_dump of: string(25) "sdfgsdfg sdfgsdfsdfg"

Comment: can you pls. do `var_dump(nl2br(:::))`

Comment: string(43) "sdfgsdfg
<NEW LINE JUST SHOWS AS BLANK>
<NEW LINE JUST SHOWS AS BLANK>
sdfgsdfsdfg"

Comment: Sorry, that's strange, I have no idea atm and unfortunately have no time to  build a test-case,,, :((

Comment: Alright, well thank you for the help you could provide! No worries about the rest... I'll figure it out

Comment: Good luck! I'll keep an eye here to see how the story ends ;-)