# Multiple <br /><br><br/>\r\n occurences needs to be replaced with <br />

Tags: php, str-replace, paragraphs

I need to replace multiple occurences of `<br />`, `<br>`, `<br/>`, `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` with only 1 `<br />`, but only where it shows up together so that I can split paragraphs into an array and trim out the last line break of `br` tag at the end of the string...

An Example of a string could be as follows:

```
This is paragraph 1<br>

This is paragraph 2<br /><br>



This is paragraph 3
This is paragraph 4


This is paragraph 5<br/>
This is paragraph 6


This is paragraph 7<br />This is paragraph 8

This is paragraph 9<br>
```

What I've tried:

```
$description = !empty($results['Description']) ? strip_tags(rtrim(str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\r\n", "<br>", "<br/>", "<br />"), array("<br />"), $results['Description']), '<br />'), '<br><a>') : '';

$paragraphs = array_filter(explode("<br />", $description));
```

But this trims out all line breaks.  I need to maintain line breaks where they are in the string, but only want to do 1 linebreak and remove all others.  How to do this?

Note:  I am using strip_tags because I want to only allow `<br>` and `<a>` tags in the `$description` string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738439/how-to-regex-replace-multiple-br-tags-with-one-br-tag)

Comment: Mine is not just `br` tags, but includes both `br` and `\r`, `\n`

Comment: But why doesn't my code work?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you're replacing every occurrence of `<br />`, `\n`, `\r` and `\n\r` with `<br />`. So, for `test<br />\n\r\<br />` your code will generate `test<br /><br /><br />`. The solution that @Virb pointed you to deals exactly with that. Of course you'll need to modify that code to include also `\n`, `\r`, etc., but it does solve your problem.

Comment: use can use trim & implode

Comment: First use regex to combine `<br>` and then use `str_replace` on `\r\n`

Comment: As @CharlotteDunois told, you can use this regex. `$string = preg_replace("#(<br\s*/?>\s*){2,}#","<br />",$string);` and then use `str_replace` on `\r` and `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try first exploding with end of line (`PHP_EOL`), strip out everything but the `<a>`, then `array_filter()`, `implode()`, and `trim()`:

```
$str    =   'This is paragraph 1<br>

This is paragraph 2<br /><br>



This is paragraph 3
This is paragraph 4


This is paragraph 5<br/>
This is paragraph 6


This is paragraph 7<br />';

$str    =   trim(implode('<br />'.PHP_EOL,array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL,strip_tags($str,'<a>')))));

echo $str;
```

**Gives you:**

```
This is paragraph 1<br />
This is paragraph 2<br />
This is paragraph 3<br />
This is paragraph 4<br />
This is paragraph 5<br />
This is paragraph 6<br />
This is paragraph 7
```

---

**Your second scenario:**

```
$str    =   'This is paragraph 1<br>

This is paragraph 2<br /><br>



This is paragraph 3
This is paragraph 4


This is paragraph 5<br/>This is paragraph 5
This is paragraph 6


This is paragraph 7<br />';

# Explode on line breaks and remove empty lines
$exp    =   array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL,$str));
# Loop array and filter the lines
$new    =   array_map(function($v) {
                return strip_tags(trim($v,'<br>,<br />,<br/>'),'<a><br>');
            },$exp);
# Implode the array back
echo implode('<br />'.PHP_EOL,$new);
```

**Gives you:**

```
This is paragraph 1<br />
This is paragraph 2<br />
This is paragraph 3<br />
This is paragraph 4<br />
This is paragraph 5<br/>This is paragraph 5<br />
This is paragraph 6<br />
This is paragraph 7
```

Comment: I updated question, there can exist a `br` tag without a line break.

Comment: The non-line break is then a problem with the `<br>` in between. The scenario is still close then, instead of imploding, just foreach loop and trim off the `<br>` and `<br />`

Comment: This is giving me 2 `<br>` elements between each paragraph.

Comment: Hmm, I think wrapping each paragraph in a `p` tag is a better solution than using `br` now.

Comment: I just updated your second scenario. It uses `array_map` instead, but same idea.