# Prevent <br> after <div>

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to remove all `<br/>` existing **right after** a div tag. Is this possible? As soon as some regular text has been printed after the `<div>` tag, `<br/>` should be allowed again.

The `<br/>` is added because of nl2br.

I don't want the users to be able to break the formatting of my pages by hitting enter a lot. This would be great to be able to fix.

Thank you.

Comment: How does the user create those `div` tags? Please explain what is happening, there might be a better solution than replacing those `br`s.

Comment: @bazmegakapa: The user types in [title]wagawaga[/title], after that some regular text. A new div tag is created with the regular text, it looks like this; 

`<div class="Title">Boom! You're done!</div><div class="Content"> <br>There are some additional...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/<div>(<br[^>]*>\s*)+/', '<div>', '$string');
```

This is based on: [How to convert multiple <br/> tag to a single <br/> tag in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php)

Comment: One question though - is there any way to also remove any whitespaces between `<div>` and `<br>`?

Comment: `/<div>(\s*<br[^>]*>\s*){2,}/` - \s stands for whitespace

Comment: BTW, this is a great tool for regex: http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Comment: Wow, thanks! One more thing, how do I remove `<br>` **before** the `</div>`?

Comment: Oh, come on, that's your homework for today ;) Brackets mean "optional", + after brackets means "one or more".

Comment: `<div class="xy"><br/></div>`

Comment: @alekwisnia: :) Alright, I've honestly tried to turn it around, but I can't get it to work. Unfortunately I'm totally new to those regex tools. Here's what I came up with: `preg_replace('/(\s*<br[^>]*>\s*){1,}</div>/','</div>',$string);`... Does **not** work. :(

Comment: Because '/' needs to be escaped by '\' - now your expression ends right after '<' in your div closing tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Works incredibly well. :)

Answer (score 2):

The better solution is to prevent `nl2br()` from putting the HTML-breaks at the beginning and end of the string.

```
$text = nl2br(trim($text));
```

Comment: It sure is, however these linebreaks I want to remove occurs wherever in the string, depending on what the user is writing.

Answer (score 1):

A simple str_replace will sort it, just check which sort of `<br>` `<br/>` `<br />` tag that `nl2br()` is using,

```
$string = str_replace('</div><br />' , '</div>' , $string);
```

Comment: but it doesnt help with </div>< br /><br /><br /> which is another problem if i understand correctly. I would use a regex for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however since I can't be sure how many times the user has pressed enter, ie there could be 30 br/s.

Comment: @alekwisnia: cause I want to allow `<br />` otherwise. It's just in the very beginning of the `<div>` I don't want them to be allowed.

Comment: Fix the problem with multiple <br/> see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8399723/956397

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 1;
while ($count != 0)
{
    $string = str_replace('</div><br/>' , '</div>' , $string, $count);
}
```