# How to convert multiple <br> to twice <br> tag in php

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to remove a concurrence br tag to two tags for the maximum. a tag is 
 not 
 here is similar question [How to convert multiple <br/> tag to a single <br/> tag in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133571/how-to-convert-multiple-br-tag-to-a-single-br-tag-in-php) but not for my problem.

how to do that with php?
This is my code but it doesn't work why?

```
$s = "line1<br><br><br><br>line2";
preg_replace("/(<br>\s*){2,}/", "<br><br>", $s);
```

Here is result i got

```
line1<br><br><br><br>line2
```

What i expect

```
line1<br><br>line2
```

Comment: What result do you get? Please tell us what doesn't work.

Comment: indeed `preg_replace` is a function (so it returns the result).